# How do I avoid getting "unexpected token Var" in JavaScript when using loops

Tags: javascript, while-loop

I'm trying to count the number of e's in a string and then display it using a while loop I keep getting `"Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token var"` when running my code, any idea how to fix this issue?

```
var sentence = "I'm learning JavaScript in my web development module.";
var charLength = sentence.length;
var count = 0;

while(var z=0;z!=charLength;z++;){
    if(sentence.CharAt(z)== "e" {
        count++;
    } 
}
console.log(count);
```

Comment: It looks like that means to be a `for(` loop, not a `while(` loop.

Comment: also you can define var z just outside of while condition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should close your if-statement. Like: `if(sentence.CharAt(z)== "e") {`. You forgot the last `)`. Also I wouldn't recommend doing a while loop that way. Change it to `for(var z=0; z !== charLength; z++)`. Also the `charAt` function doesn't start with a capital C. Here's the fixed function:

```
var sentence = "I'm learning JavaScript in my web development module.";
var charLength = sentence.length;
var count = 0;

for (var z = 0; z != charLength; z++) {
  if (sentence.charAt(z) === "e") {
    count++;
  }
}
console.log(count);
```

Compare it to yours and learn from it ;)

---

If you just want to make this function by checking the amount of indexes of a character/string you might aswell use a simple regex. This function could also fix your issue;

```
var sentence = "I'm learning JavaScript in my web development module.";
var count = (sentence.match(/e/g) || []).length;
console.log(count); // Logs 6
```

Comment: Noticed ;) Changing it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues with your syntax.. See below:

```
while(var z=0;z!=charLength;z++;){
^^^^^ // Make this into for    ^ //Remove this semicolon
if(sentence.CharAt(z)== "e") {
                           ^ //Put a closing bracket here.
count++;
}

}
```

And lastly, please indent.

Answer (score 0):

Use a for loop to have that syntax, or change your syntax for the while.

```
var sentence = "I'm learning JavaScript in my web development module.";
var charLength = sentence.length;
var count = 0;

for(var z = 0; z < charLength; z++){
    if(sentence[z] === "e"){
        count++;
    }
}

console.log(count);
```